# Microsoft's Microsoft Text Driver sees text as float operation

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, driver, text-files

Using .NET

I have a text file with comma separated data. One of the columns consists of text like the following : 1997/020269/07

Now when I do a select with an OdbcCommand the string is seen as a float and it returns the 'answer' instead of the actual text!

How can I get the actual text? Am I going to be forced to parsing the file manually?

Hope someone can help...please?! :)

Edit: Some code maybe? :)

```
string strConnString =
            @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" + _FilePath +
            @"; Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;Persist Security Info=False";

var conn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(strConnString);

var cmd = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand("select MyColumn from TextFile.txt", conn);
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


while (reader.Read())
{ Console.WriteLine(reader["MyColumn"]); }
```

This returns  0.014074977 instead of 1997/020269/07

Comment: Nobody can help you. You didn't show the code you used. You didn't even show what this "answer" is. You will never know the answer.

Comment: You rock. I laughed my ass of just now. My Bad.

Comment: @Tersius: Sometimes a poke with a sharp stick is more effective than a tap on the shoulder. I hope the sharp stick hurts for a little while - and you'll remember it.

Comment: Meanwhile, I can save anyone else the trouble, (1997 / 020269) / 07 is in fact 0.014074977270004158355828393817441.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a [schema.ini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28VS.85%29.aspx) file -- these can be used to explicitly define the format of the text file, including data types.

Your schema.ini file might end up looking a little like:

```
[sourcefilename.txt]
ColNameHeader=true
Format=CSVDelimited
Col1=MyColumn Text Width 14
Col2=...
```

Comment: Nice link. I hope you'll elaborate just a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Try using schema.ini

```
[yourfile.txt]
ColNameHeader=false
MaxScanRows=0
Format=FixedLength
Col1=MyColumn Text Width 20
```

Bye.